# Why is the hypothesis of continuous differentiability necessary for integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is probably a dumb question but I don't quite get why  the hypothesis that $g'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ is necessary for the theorem

$$\int_a^b (f \circ g) \ g' = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f$$

to hold. Almost all of the sources I have seen assume this hypothesis, even though it is not used explicitly in the proof. Why is it not enough for $g'$ to merely be integrable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need in the proof is to make sure that $(F \circ g) (t)$ is the primitive of the function $$t \mapsto f(g(t)) \cdot g'(t)$$

which needs only to be **integrable** to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Therefore you need to garantee that $g'$ is at least  integrable.

**Notes:**

- The product of Riemann integrable functions is integrable;
- A continuous function is integrable.